# IntelliJ runs its own interpretation of the processResources gradle task

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

When running or debugging a Java application in IntelliJ, the resources that are bundled within the `src` folder need to be processed. If the actual application happens to be a gradle project, IntelliJ would need to run the `processResources` task in order to *compile* the resources into the `build` folder. This is the ideal situation.

In reality, IntelliJ will look over that task and construct its own interpretation of what it will see in there. The only advantage of doing this is the speed, but on the other hand, this approach imposes huge constraints on how the resources are handled. This is working fine if your build omits the `processResources` task, relying on the default behavior. But if you need to have a more complex `processResources` implementation, there is a very low chance IntelliJ will make a right guess with its own interpretation.

My question: is there a way to suppress this behavior? I'd rather prefer relying on the pure execution of the gradle `processResources` task.

I have also put together a little project to demonstrate my hypothesis.
https://github.com/nucatus/idea-gradle-processresourecs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ 2016.3 or later, you can delegate the IDE build/run config to Gradle.

Go to:

Settings->Build, Execution, and Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Runner

Check the box next to Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle.

See: https://dzone.com/articles/using-idea-to-delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-gr